# Area of a rotational solid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The following problem has stumped me:

The region is bounded by the graphs of y=$\sqrt{x}$, $y=0$, and $x= 4$.
Find the volume of a solid found by rotating the region about the axis $x=6$.

The outer boundary I choose was $(6-y^2)$ but have no idea on how to write the expression of the inner boundary.

[image]

**More important than the answer could you please explain why and which outer and inner edges we will choose.**

Also I have been trying to integrate with respect to the $y-axis$, because $x=6$ is parallel to it. Is that correct?
[image]

Comment: For a given $y$, can you sketch what one such washer would look like? I suggest doing it on the picture you have posted.

Comment: @DavidHill can you give me an idea by what you mean by washer? In class we were just told it is the name of method.

Comment: @DavidHill Do you mean the 3rd dimensional representation of the solid?

Comment: Yes, after you rotate the region you get a solid. Take a slice perpendicular to the axis of rotation. It looks like a washer. Didn't your instructor draw any pictures in class?

Comment: @ David Hill unfortunately no. We did talk about representative rectangles.

Comment: @DavidHill Ive edited in a picture. I hope thats what you mean

Answer (score 1):

[image: washer]

Here is a picture of one of the washers obtained. This is what I meant in my comment.